# Laravel single vs multiple controllers & db row vs column

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, model-view-controller

1. Suppose 20 thousand people each day use my laravel app. I have created One controller that contains about 200 methods. On the other hand I have created 20 controllers with 10 methods each. Which one is a better approach and does it affect the app's performance?
2. Suppose I want to store 5 portfolio image of each user. I can think of 2 ways. One is inserting one row for each portfolio image on a table-> contains `id | user_id | portfolio` other is creating 5 columns like -> `id | user_id | portfolio_1 | portfolio_2 | ... etc` which one is a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, a controller with 200 methods is way too many... consider the SRP (single responsibility) principle of [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)).

And it's generally far better to normalize your database properly, rather than to have numbered columns for each portfolio.... what happens when somebody wants to add more portfolios than you have numbered columns? Using numbered columns restricts you, forcing you to change your database structure as you decide to increase it; properly normalized database doesn't limit you, no code or database changes necessary (other than perhaps a configuration setting)

Answer (score 0):

For the 200 method controller every time call, php syntax parser have to parse the whole controller. And for the 20 method controller syntax parser have parse less amount of code because we usually call a single controller at a time.

And for the portfolio image storing the first method if more preferable.
Because at the time of displaying them for the first method probably you can iterate through $user->portfolio() and showing them in html.

But for the second method you have to write almost same html 5 time. For the first method also you can increase number of portfolio image any time.